# Correct dispose bitmap c# to global bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap, dispose

When when i just .Dispose main Bitmap (bmp1) the static Global_bitmap = null

Code looks like :

```
    private Bitmap Global_bitmap { get; private set; }
    void move_bmp_to_global_variable()
    {
     while(true)
      {
      Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(screen1);
      Global_bitmap = bmp1
      bmp1.Dispose();
      }
    }
```

How can i just set Global_bitmap = bmp1 and dispose bmp1? I want overwrite Global_bitmap and still have the same memory usage.

Comment: If the reference has to be kept around, why do you want to dispose it? This question doesn't make sense

Comment: apparently, he does not want to keep the reference and wants to just keep the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clone your bitmap and assign it Global_bitmap:

```
Global_bitmap = bmp1.Clone();
bmp1.Dispose();
```